# Java class field variable cannot be resolved

Tags: java

Eclipse shows error "Variable cannot be resolved" for fields `dc_departureDate` and `dc_arrivalDate`.

[image: IDE error]

```
private Flight getinputFlightData() {
        if (textField_FlightId.getText().isEmpty())
            return null;
        int flightID = Integer.parseInt(textField_FlightId.getText());
        String departureAirport = textField_departureAirport.getText();
        String arrivalAirport = textField_arrivalAirport.getText();
        Date departureTime = dc_departureDate.getDate();
        Date arrivalTime = dc_arrivalDate.getDate();;

        short flightSeats = Byte.parseByte(textField_FlightSeats.getText());
        float flightPrice = Float.parseFloat(textField_FlightPrice.getText());
        boolean isDelayed = Boolean.parseBoolean(textField_isDelayed.getText());

        Flight flight = new Flight(flightID, departureAirport, arrivalAirport, departureTime, arrivalTime, flightSeats, flightPrice, isDelayed);
        return flight;
    }
```

Comment: Include the picture directly. If it is text, then don't paste as picture. `JDateChooser` is not a default java class. You will have to add the dependency

Comment: I tried to find duplicate, but all I could find are "variable defined inside block" type of questions instead of class fields. Is there any?

Answer (score 0):

`dc_departureDate` and `dc_arrivalDate` are not defined as class fields. Instead you defined them only as local variables in upper method (name is not in the picture). You probably wanted them to be defined on class level like `textField_FlightId` is.